# Why is recursion in javascript so slow?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I just ran this  benchmark on jsperf: https://jsperf.com/mapping1

I was trying to see if a map that used recursion could beat the `Array.prototype` map function. Mine lost. Horribly. Can someone explain why?

```
map = function(f, xs) {
    if (xs.length === 0) {return []}
    return [f(head(xs))].concat(map(f, tail(xs)))
}

// head() and tail() do exactly what you would expect. I wish there was a way to programmatically fork lists in js...
```

Comment: [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) creates a new array, for one.

Comment: so does `Array.prototype.map()` i thought?

Comment: Those are no cons lists, they are arrays. `slice` (in `tail`?) and `concat` are not `O(1)`.

Comment: As does `[<elem>]`. You're probably also slicing the array in head and tail, while map is working on the array in-place and putting the aggregated output into a single new array.

Comment: @dopatraman: Yes, but `Array::map` does create only a single one. Your function creates 3 new arrays on every single recursion step.

Comment: ofcourse... i see that now

Comment: Also, your `head` function does *not* do what one would expect: It returns an array, not an element. `add` will have to type-cast that into a string and …

Comment: Even if you just made one array and iterated over the values it would be slower than the supplied primitives, Libraries such as underscore usually just wrap the primitives when they're available since you cannot beat them. (Though performance might sometimes be better on bytecode compiled own versions it won't beat the average speed)

Comment: Try running your recursion with memoization.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you think a recursive method could ever beat the native version, which is almost certainly implemented iteratively? A recursive function can't be as performant as an iterative one unless tail-calls are supported, and even then it will be simply because that support essentially unrolls the recursive function into the iterative version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation of fasterMap recursively, but without concat, it is 20x faster than map and only 1.5x slower than native Array.map:

```
var Cx = function(){
    this.map = function (f, xs) {
        if (xs.length === 0) {return []}
        return [f(head(xs))].concat(arguments.callee(f, tail(xs)))
    }

    this.fasterMap = function(f, xs, i) {
        i = i || 0;
        if (xs.length === 0 || i > xs.length - 1) {return []}
        xs[i] = f(xs[i])
        arguments.callee(f, xs, i + 1)
        return xs
    }

    this.arrMap = function (f, xs) {
        return xs.map(f)
    }
}

function head(arr){return arr[0]}
function tail(arr){return arr.slice(1)}

function add1(x){return x + 1}

function rep(n,f){
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f(i)
}

var cx = new Cx()

;[9,99,999].forEach(function(n){
    var test = []
    rep(n,function(i){test.push(i + 1)})

    ;['map','fasterMap','arrMap'].forEach(function(mapType){
        var mapFn = function(){return cx[mapType](add1,test)}
        if(n < 10)
            console.log('    ' + mapType,mapFn())
        else{
            console.time('    ' + mapType + ' ' + n)
            rep(1000,mapFn)
            console.timeEnd('    ' + mapType + ' ' + n)
        }
    })
})
```

Here are test results on Cloud9 IDE:

```
map [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
fasterMap [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
arrMap [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                

map 99: 45ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
fasterMap 99: 8ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
arrMap 99: 7ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

map 999: 2227ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
fasterMap 999: 102ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
arrMap 999: 85ms
```

So the answer is concat makes your map function slow.